# How to check if sprite node change position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My sprite node change position on the screen. And I need to detect when sprite move to up, move to down, move to left, move to right.

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable **oldPosition** and keep track of the sprite position in the **update:** method:

```
var oldPosition: CGPoint?

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered

        if Int((oldPosition?.x)!) > Int((sprite?.position.x)!) {
            // sprite moves to the left

        } else if Int((oldPosition?.x)!) < Int((sprite?.position.x)!) {
            // sprite moves to the right

        }

        if Int((oldPosition?.y)!) > Int((sprite?.position.y)!) {
            // sprite moves down

        } else if Int((oldPosition?.y)!) < Int((sprite?.position.y)!) {
            // sprite moves up

        }

        // keep track
        oldPosition = sprite?.position
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You are going to want to keep track of this within the sprite, not as a separate variable.  `userData` is perfect for this. `sprite!.userDate!["oldPosition"] = sprite!.position`

Answer (score 0):

You’ve got two options here. As you’ve not posted any code I can’t really advise which is the best:

1. If you’ve sub-classed SKNode, then override the frame property to add a didSet observer clause:

   override var frame : CGRect {

   ```
   didSet {
        // compute the change in the frame’s origin
        let delta : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.origin.x - oldValue.origin.x,
                                                           y: frame.origin.y - oldValue.origin.y)

        // etc
    }
   ```

   }

See SKNode docs at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode

2. If you don’t want to subclass, you can use NSNotificationCenter to add an observer to your node via addObserver:selector:name:object: . See the documentation at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

I’d probably go for option 1.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I change position of SpriteNode using SKAction. And when my sprite move to right, sprite must change images for sprite(we must see how cat walk to the right side). For example, cat move to right, then cat move to down.And we must to see how cat walk to the right side, then cat continue walk to the down side. In my code  cat move to the right because SKAction's sprite.run not change. That's why i need  if...else if...else Statement for checking and detecting changes of sprite.

Comment: position will not get called on an SKAction, it access the variable directly, so neither of these methods will work.

Comment: @Proffan, is your cat walking on a path?  you can just script a sequence of SKAction's together